# file_exists para verificar noticias

Tags: php

Olá, estou tendo problemas com meu código. A ideia inicial dele é percorrer o servidor e mostrar os links referentes à notícia.

```
<?php
$inicio=180;

if(file_exists("http://www.sitequalquer.com.br/noticia_".$inicio.".htm")){

      while($inicio){

        echo '<a href="http://www.sitequalquer.com.br/noticia_'.$inicio.'.htm">noticia'.$inicio.'</a><br>';

        $inicio++;

      }

    }else{

        echo "http://www.sitequalquer.com.br/noticia_".$inicio.".htm";
    }

?>
```

Eu estou rodando este código em minha máquina; mas não tenho conhecimento se o comando `file_exists` funciona para percorrer arquivos externos.

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? A função `file_exists` não funciona para URLs.

Comment: eu não sabia que a função `file_exists` não funcionava para url's, gostaria de saber alguma coisa que possa verificar o link e se ele existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `file_exists` funciona apenas para arquivo locais.

O certo é usar o `curl` pra fazer a conexão com a página desejada e verificar se a resposta é válida.

Geralmente verificar o código de *status* da resposta já resolve (por exemplo, 404 para páginas não encontradas) mas sites menos elaborados podem acabar retornando 200 para páginas não encontradas. Nesses caso é bom analisar o conteúdo da página recebida.

Comment: Lembrando também que existe sempre a possibilidade do servidor retornar um redirect 301. Nesse caso seria necessário seguir a URL informada e então verificar se existe.

Comment: Obrigado @Rodrigo Rigotti com uma boa leitura obtive sucesso, foi relativamente mais simples do que pensei, apenas fiz a verificação com o `curl` e criei laço de repetição. Valeu mesmo

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` funciona apenas para caminhos absolutos, ou seja, dentro do filesystem do servidor.
Aconselho verificar se [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) retorna código 200, e não 404, para o que você quer fazer.